# Eclipse Browser has problems with rest api call

Tags: eclipse, browser

I have a problem with my eclipse browser.

If i call the url of my sonarqube server (https://sonar) everthing works fine and eclipse shows me the page. But if i try to call the api (https://sonar/api/system/status) it returns with an error window which says that the page could not be opened. The same url worked for me in *normal* browsers.

**Question**

Does eclipse browser has problems with calling rest apis in general? Or is there something i could do to make it work?

**System:**

- Windows 10 Pro (10.0.15063 Build 15063)
- Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Comment: A hint why this question was downvoted would help me to ask better questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be in IE (which is used by eclipse in default). If i call the url in IE it wants to download the json answer. I changed some values in registry so IE just show me the json in browser directly. After that also eclipse could show me hte result without error.

Here is my ie_json.reg file i executed to change values in registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00;
; Tell IE 7,8,9,10 to open JSON documents in the browser on Windows XP and later.
; 25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13 is the CLSID for the "Browse in place" .
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

I found this solution at http://developers.de/blogs/holger_vetter/archive/2013/12/13/view-json-in-internet-explorer-7-11.aspx